# Rendering only the URL from a Drupal 7 custom field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a hard time rendering just the url (no title, div markup, etc) for a custom field within custom node display of `node--My_Content_Type_Node.tpl.php`. I have been attempting to go the route outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727234/extract-url-from-link-field-in-drupal), but have been having a tough time. Here are my specifics:

My custom field is a Taxonomy term reference to forums, with the machine name of `taxonomy_forums`

I have been trying to use the following (along with subtle variations), with no success:

```
$url = render($node->taxonomy_forums[$node->language][0]['url']);
```

Essentially, I am trying to tie content to a specific precreated forum for comment, and create a link to it.

I can display the default layout (link, title, markup) by using the following, but no luck seperating it out:

```
$Forum = render($content['taxonomy_forums']);
```

Any help greatly appreciated, and this is my first post here, so please let me know if any more details are needed.

Thanks!

Update: Recaiving the following for the var dump:

`array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["tid"]=> string(1) "5" ["taxonomy_term"]=> object(stdClass)#81 (8) { ["tid"]=> string(1) "5" ["vid"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(13) "Total Rewards" ["description"]=> string(167) "Use this space to ask questions, make comments, or start a conversation with Grameen Foundation and other site users related to assessing your total rewards practices." ["format"]=> NULL ["weight"]=> string(1) "4" ["vocabulary_machine_name"]=> string(6) "forums" ["rdf_mapping"]=> array(5) { ["rdftype"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "sioc:Container" [1]=> string(10) "sioc:Forum" } ["name"]=> array(1) { ["predicates"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "rdfs:label" [1]=> string(14) "skos:prefLabel" } } ["description"]=> array(1) { ["predicates"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "skos:definition" } } ["vid"]=> array(2) { ["predicates"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "skos:inScheme" } ["type"]=> string(3) "rel" } ["parent"]=> array(2) { ["predicates"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "skos:broader" } ["type"]=> string(3) "rel" } } } } } }`

Comment: Do you get any errors, or does $url contain no data when you output it? Have you done a `var_dump($node->taxonomy_forums);` to see what's actually in there?

Comment: Terry, I'm receiving the following code, edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render just a url you can check this function [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7). You can specify if you need absolute or relative url. So if you need absolute url then code can looks like:

```
$url = url($node->taxonomy_forums[$node->language][0]['url'], array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

And you need to make sure that `$node->taxonomy_forums[$node->language][0]['url']` is proper array structure. You might can check it via devel function `dsm($node->taxonomy_forums)`. Just make sure that devel module installed.

Comment: Thanks Vadim! Your suggestion for using devel helped me figure it out, thanks again.